# Correct "conjunction" in this sentence

Tags: conjunctions

I was on my way to school and suddenly heard my friend, A, is calling out from a distance:

> **Why are you going to school!**
>
> **Today is a holiday!**

My friend is using **two** sentences to express this. But if I would like to express it in **one sentence** how am I to say?

Can I say:

> Why are you going to school **as** it's a holiday today.

Does it convey the meaning that I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those *words* are fine. although, stylistically, if you use them, you would put a comma after *school*.

Comment: @JasonBassford So "as" is fine here

Comment: I wouldn't call it *wrong*; however, it's a little awkward. It would likely be more natural to say *Why are you going to school on a holiday?* or *Why are you going to school? Don't you know it's a holiday?* Or even reverse their order. *It's a holiday today. Why are you going to school?*

Answer (score -2):

No, that sentence isn't natural. "As" is used to introduce an explanation for a previous *statement*, but not for the confusion expressed in a previous *question*.

In general English doesn't like to combine statements and questions into the same sentence. You could write,

> It's a holiday today, why are you going to school?

But that's just fusing together too sentences:

> It's a holiday today! Why are you going to school?

By the way, you wouldn't write

> Why are you going to school!

It's a question, so you need a question mark. If you really want you can use both ("?!") but that's not really standard.